# Модуль Yii2 attachment не найден

Tags: yii2, yii

Установил расширение [Nemmo/yii2-attachments](https://github.com/Nemmo/yii2-attachments), и настроил все по инструкции, но при миграции выдает ошибку что модуль не найден.
Вот лог ошибки

```
Exception 'Exception' with message 'Yii2 attachment module not found, may be you didn't add it to your config?'

in D:\OpenServer\domains\univer.lc\vendor\nemmo\yii2-attachments\src\ModuleTrait.php:30
```

Моя конфигурация `app\config\web.php`

```
'modules' => [
        'attachments' => [
            'class' => nemmo\attachments\Module::className(),
            'tempPath' => '@app/upload/file/temp',
            'storePath' => '@app/upload/file/store',
            'rules' => [ // Rules according to the FileValidator
                'maxFiles' => 10, // Allow to upload maximum 3 files, default to 3
                'mimeTypes' => 'image/png', // Only png images
                'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 // 1 MB
            ],
            'tableName' => '{{%attachments}}' // Optional, default to 'attach_file'
        ],
```

Файл `app\config\console.php`

```
'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'nemmo\attachments\migrations',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Скажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы все работало нужно добавить модуль attachments в config/console.php